# How to supply policyDocument in CfnBucketPolicy in AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

How do I supply custom policy in CfnBucketPolicy in AWS CDK. The help is really appreciated.

```
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    //creating s3 bucket
    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'MyFirstBucket', {
      versioned: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.KMS
    });

    //creating Policy Document for s3 bucket
    const bucketPolicy = new s3.CfnBucketPolicy(this,'MyFirstPolicy', {
      bucket: bucket.bucketName,
      policyDocument:
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a PolicyDocument instance via the `@aws-cdk/aws-iam.PolicyDocument` class, then assign that in your bucket policy.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.PolicyDocument.html

This will require you to add any policy statements as a `PolicyStatement` instance, and can be added during object creation or via the `addStatements` method.